# How to solve a git stash conflict

Tags: git, github, version-control, github-actions, git-stash

[image]

Hi guys I have the following issue.

- I performed a git stash first
- Then a git pull
- then sorted out the conflicts
- Now I am trying to do a git stash pop so as to bring back the changes I made and add them to my project and I am getting the above messages for each of the stashed files

Help, how do I proceed?

I have tried doing `git stash pop` to get the stashed files back

Comment: I would start by looking into what is actually changed ```git stash show -p``` Then decide what to do

Comment: Thanks I actually found that I did not add the files I merged conflicts in using `git add .`, after that everything was OK